# Function that outputs multiple datasets

Tags: loops, dataset

I am working in MATLAB.
I have a function that loops through all the files in a directory, runs them and concatenates their dataset outputs into a single dataset.

Is there a way that I can alter my function so that it outputs all the individual datasets as well as the unified one?

Below, the array named "FileInfo" has 3 columns. The first has the file name, and the second and third columns are the inputs

```
 function [AllFunOutputs] = RunAllFuns(FileInfo)     
 fileDir  = dir('C:\MATLAB\Funs');   % get all file names in directory 'Funs'
 files = {fileDir.name};                             
 funNames = strrep(files, '.m', '');  % strip the '.m' suffix from all files 
 funNames(:,1:2) = [];    
 funNames = transpose(funNames);

k = 1;               % below, match the function name with its argument
  for i=1:length(FileInfo)
    if strcmp(FileInfo(i,1),funNames(k,1))
      funNames(k,3) = FileInfo(i,2);
      k = k+1; 
     end
 end

                % create function handles

 fh_array = cellfun(@str2func,{funNames{:,1}},'UniformOutput', false);  

    X = [];     % below, concatenate all output datasets into a single dataset 

   for i=1:size((funNames),1) 
    X=[fh_array{i}(funNames(i,2),(funNames(i,3)))];
    X = X+1;
   end
```

so..... why doesn't this work to give me the output dataset of all the functions?

```
nFcns = numel(fh_array);    % number of functions to evaluate 

    for i=1:size(nFcns)  
    [allresults] = feval(@(i)funNames(i,2),funNames(i,3));   
    end
```

Thank you so much for your help and time!